# Find pattern in files with java 8

Tags: java, regex, java-8

consider I have a file like (just an excerpt)

```
name: 'foobar'
```

I like to retrieve `foobar` when I discover the line with `name`.

My current approach is

```
Pattern m = Pattern.compile("name: '(.+)'");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(ruleFile)) {
    Optional<String> message = lines.filter(m.asPredicate()).findFirst();
    if (message.isPresent()) {
        Matcher matcher = m.matcher(message.get());
        matcher.find();
        String group = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(group);
    }
}
```

which looks not nice. The excessive use of the pattern and matcher seems wrong.

Is there a easier/better way ? Especially if I have multiple keys I like to search like this ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would expect something more like this, to avoid matching the pattern twice:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("name: '([^']*)'");
lines.map(p::matcher)
     .filter(Matcher::matches)
     .findFirst()
     .ifPresent(matcher -> System.out.println(matcher.group(1)));
```

That is, for each string's matcher, get the first one that matches, for that one print out the first group.

Comment: The `map(p::matcher)` pipeline stage creates a new `Matcher` object for each line that is read in.  For extremely large files, this can be a source of inefficiency.  Instead, a reusable `Matcher` object can be created, and `.map(matcher::reset)` may be used to map from the line just read in into the reusable `matcher`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877960/3690024).  Re-using stateful objects in stream pipelines violates all kinds of rules, so I'd only recommend this if you are reading large files, and determine this to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 7):

This is how the Java 9 solution will most likely look like:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("name: '(.+)'").matcher("");
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(ruleFile)) {
    lines.flatMap(line -> m.reset(line).results().limit(1))
         .forEach(mr -> System.out.println(mr.group(1)));
}
```

It uses the method [`Matcher.results()`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) which returns a stream of all matches. Combining a stream of lines with a stream of matches via `flatMap` allows us to process all matches of a file. Since your original code only processes the first match of a line, I simply added a `limit(1)` to the matches of each line to get the same behavior.

Unfortunately, this feature is missing in Java 8, however, sneaking into upcoming releases helps getting an idea how an interim solution may look like:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("name: '(.+)'").matcher("");
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(ruleFile)) {
    lines.flatMap(line -> m.reset(line).find()? Stream.of(m.toMatchResult()): null)
         .forEach(mr -> System.out.println(mr.group(1)));
}
```

To simplify the sub-stream creation, this solution utilizes that only the first match is intended and creates a single element stream in the first place.

But note that with the question’s pattern `'name: '(.+)'` it doesn’t matter whether we limit the number of matches as `.+` will greedily match all characters up to the last follow-up `'` of the line, so another match is impossible. Things are different when using a reluctant quantifier like with `name: '(.*?)'` which consumes up to the *next* `'` rather than the *last* one or forbidding to skip past `'` explicitly, as with `name: '([^']*)'`.

---

The solutions above use a shared `Matcher` which works well with single-threaded usage (and this is unlikely to ever benefit from parallel processing). But if you want to be on the thread safe side, you may only share a `Pattern` and create a `Matcher` instead of calling `m.reset(line)`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name: '(.*)'");
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(ruleFile)) {
    lines.flatMap(line -> pattern.matcher(line).results().limit(1))
         .forEach(mr -> System.out.println(mr.group(1)));
}
```

resp. with Java 8

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(ruleFile)) {
    lines.flatMap(line -> {Matcher m=pattern.matcher(line);
                           return m.find()? Stream.of(m.toMatchResult()): null;})
         .forEach(mr -> System.out.println(mr.group(1)));
}
```

which isn’t that concise due to the introduction of a local variable. This can be avoided by a preceding `map` operation, but when we are at this point, as long as we only head for a single match per line, we don’t need a `flatMap` then:

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(ruleFile)) {
    lines.map(pattern::matcher).filter(Matcher::find)
         .forEach(m -> System.out.println(m.group(1)));
}
```

Since each `Matcher` is used exactly once, in a non-interfering way, its mutable nature doesn’t hurt here and a conversion to an immutable `MatchResult` becomes unnecessary.

However, these solutions can’t be scaled to process multiple matches per line, if that ever becomes necessary…

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @khelwood results in creating a new `Matcher` object over and over again, which can be a source of inefficiency if long files are scanned.

The following solution creates the matcher only once, and reuses it for each line in the file.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("name: '([^']*)'");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(""); // Create a matcher for the pattern

Files.lines(ruleFile)
    .map(matcher::reset)         // Reuse the matcher object
    .filter(Matcher::matches)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(m -> System.out.println(m.group(1)));
```

**Warning -- Suspicious Hack Ahead**

The `.map(matcher::reset)` pipeline stage is where the magic/hack happens.  It effectively calls `matcher.reset(line)`, which resets `matcher` to perform the next matching on the line just read in from the file, and returns itself, to allow chaining calls.  The `.map(...)` stream operator sees this as mapping from the line to a `Matcher` object, but in reality, we keep mapping to same object `matcher` each time, violating all sorts of rules about side-effects, etc.

Of course, this **cannot** be used for parallel streams, but fortunately reading from a file is inherently sequential.

Hack or Optimization?  I suppose up/down votes will decide.