# regex - Find pattern in file with java-8

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I have found the following solution from a similar question. Here is the link:

[Find pattern in files with java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791138/find-pattern-in-files-with-java-8)

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("is '(.+)'");
    stream1.map(p::matcher)
         .filter(Matcher::matches)
         .findFirst()
         .ifPresent(matcher -> System.out.println(matcher.group(1)));
```

This is the solution given by khelwood. This is very useful to me. But I don't know why it is not printing anything.

I am trying to match anything that follows the word 'is '.

And my input file contains these lines:

```
my name is tom
my dog is hom.
```

I need to print

```
tom
hom.
```

But nothing is printed

Answer (score 3):

you can't get all of the result since `Stream#findFirst` is return the first satisfied element in a stream, please using `Stream#forEach` instead.

you should remove the symbol **`'`** that doesn't appear there at all, and replace `Matcher#matches` with `Matcher#find`, because `Matcher#matches` will matches the whole input. for example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("is (.+)");
stream1.map(p::matcher)
       .filter(Matcher::find)
       .forEach(matcher -> System.out.println(matcher.group(1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the single quotes in the regex. I am assuming since you said you want to match anything after 'is', you may want to print a blank if nothing follows 'is'; thus, the '.*' instead of '.+' in the regex I used.

This should work.

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("is (.*)");
    stream1.map(p::matcher)
         .filter(Matcher::matches)
         .filter(Matcher::find)
         .forEach(matcher -> System.out.println(matcher.group(1)));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not getting anything still