# find a pattern in a file in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a file, when I find

```
name="john"
```

I want to return `john`. I tried doing below:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        list.add(scanner.nextLine()); 
     }

    for(String str:list){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name='([^']*)'");
        if(str.contains(pattern))

    }
```

and here I don't know how to continue, how do I return it? I have read the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791138/find-pattern-in-files-with-java-8) but can't make it work.

Comment: The accepted answer in the other question does basically exactly what you want, except you could change ifPresent() to orElse("") to return an empty string if there's no match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current pattern is incorrect, it expects `'` while the file is using `"`. You might want to improve the pattern further, but the whole problem can be accomplished with streams:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name=\"(.+)\"");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
  return reader.lines()
      .map(pattern::matcher)
      .filter(Matcher::matches)
      .map(m -> m.group(1))
      .findFirst()
      .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

Comment: thankyou, how do i return the value though, i don't want to print it but to return it,not familiar with streams

Comment: @alice changed to code to return the first name in the file or throw `IllegalArgumentException` if no name is found

Comment: wait, it works only if the entire line is name="something",but if i have something else before and after name="" it does throw the exception

Comment: @alice pattern `name=\"(.+)\"` assumes that `name="john"` is all there is in the related file line. If you have it in the middle of the line e.g. `a="b" name="john" 1="2"` you need change the pattern to handle it e.g. `.*name="(.+)".*`. The final pattern depends on your input file and error handling strategy.

Comment: yes, i wanted only what was inside the quotes,the rest can be anything,ty again

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to use `group 1` that is being matched in the regex:
You can do it as below:

```
matcher.group(1)
```

Working example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("name=\"john\"");
for(String str:list){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name=\"([^']*)\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if(matcher.matches())
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // having the value john
    }
```

Jshell Output:

```
jshell> for(String str:list){
   ...>         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name=\"([^']*)\"");
   ...>         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
   ...>         if(matcher.matches())
   ...>             System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
   ...>     }

   john
```